# ReactiveUI Routing Replace ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms, routes, reactiveui

I would like to navigate to a new page, popping the current one.

I tried this code in a `ReactiveCommand`

```
Router.Navigate.Execute(viewModel)
     .Do(_ => Router.NavigationStack.RemoveAt(Router.NavigationStack.Count() - 2));
```

which almost does the job, but it navigates back before pushing the new page, which looks weird.

Any idea to achieve this? Kind of replacing the last ViewModel of the `Router.NavigationStack`?

Thanks!

Comment: Router.Navigate.NavigateAndReset(viewmodel) may be can do the trick

Comment: @AdriánRomero Unfortunately no because I don't want to reset the whole stack, just the last one.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer as well. Can you remote the viewmodel from NavigationStack right before calling .Navigate(vmNext)?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer if you've figured this out @Elisabeth

Comment: @phillipvoyle Unfortunately no. I stopped using ReactiveUI for Navigation as I find it slow and use Prism for Navigation. I am however interested in a solution if someone found one.

Comment: @Elisabeth maybe that is the solution. Will check prism out